# Selenium Grid WebElement gets null values

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to use selenium grid for any browser and operating system. However, I have been faced to a problem while using RemoteWebDriver. My code (which is very simple, for example clicking a button on a webpage) is running succesfully when I use firefox driver or any other WebDriver types locally, but same code is not working when the driver becomes RemoteWebDriver. It gives error for WebElements because it finds the element but set the values of it (i.e id) to null immediately afterwards. Thus the button can not be clicked or I can not get any attribute of it. Note: I used a lot of versions of grid and selenium (2.46,2.53.0,2.53.1,3.3.1,3.4 etc.) and I also tried on different machines with different OS and browsers.

```
package test.java.TestNG;

import org.junit.After;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class myGrid
{
    WebDriver driver;

    String myURL = "http://www.hepsiburada.com";

    @Test
    public void calculatepercent() throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/geckodriver");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

        String Hub = "http://IP:5555/wd/hub"; // IP is my local Ip

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Hub),capabilities);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.navigate().to(myURL);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.id("buttonProductSearch"));

        myElement.click();
    }

    @After
    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**ERROR posted on Node Terminal:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ClickElement.call(ClickElement.java:30)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ClickElement.call(ClickElement.java:22)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   14:23:59.667 WARN - Exception: null

**ERROR at IDE (Intellij Idea):**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'mek', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.0-52-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.5ZZmDH4nMl5L, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, webdriver.remote.sessionid=3738002e-e906-42b7-8657-b427981f1cb0, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=53.0.2, platformVersion=4.8.0-52-generic, moz:processID=6799.0, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=linux, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 3738002e-e906-42b7-8657-b427981f1cb0

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:82)
    at test.java.TestNG.myGrid.calculatepercent(myGrid.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ClickElement.call(ClickElement.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ClickElement.call(ClickElement.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Change `WebDriver` driver type to `RemoteWebDriver`

Comment: I also tried but it is not solved, same error again.

Comment: can u share code having @before

Comment: This is my whole code, there isn't any @before parameter in my code. It is not a necessity, this code is working when using firefoxdriver instead of remotewebdriver as I mentioned.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ClickElement.call(ClickElement.java:30)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ClickElement.call(ClickElement.java:22)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
14:23:59.667 WARN - Exception: null

Comment: This is the error posted at terminal of node side.